# Performing Matrix Vector Multiplication using Collective communication in MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to think of an approach to multiply a Matrix and a Vector using Collective communication in MPI. The result of a Matrix M X N and a vector Nx1 will be a M x 1 vector. To parallelize we could run M+1 processes and each of the M processes calculates the one element of a row in the resulting vector. I am trying to come up with an approach that involves collective communication API like MPI_Reduce. Not sure what would be an ideal approach in this case.
**My Thoughts:**
Consider one row of the matrix x1,x2,...x,n and the vector is [v1,v2,v3...vn] the first row of the resulting vector will be single element x1*v1+x2*v2+...xn*vn Now the only way to use the reduce function would be to get n processes to calculate each product xi*vi and then use MPI_Reduce to calculate the sum of all these. So the parent process will use reduce to calculate each row value. This does sound like it will work. I am not sure if there is a better way

Comment: Your approach is too fine-grained. Start out with each process having a block row of the matrix and part of the input vector, then they do an allgather of the vector and compute their part of the output.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thanks I will think over it. Is there a way to use collective communication to receive n number of data into an array of length n? Example The master process could do receive(arr,n,process_arr) so for each of the processes in process_arr, the data they return is put into an array.